# How to handle zalgo text when loading into Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, zalgo

I am getting an error:

```
String length exceeds DDL length
```

when loading from a CSV into a column in Redshift. I'm COPYING data from a source (which has zalgo text sometimes) into a CSV in s3, and loading the csv into Redshift.

This is my code when extracting data from a source into s3

```
substring(s.caption for 2000) as caption,
substring(s.location for 2000) as location,
```

and I use LOAD to move data from s3 to Redshift which is when I get the error. How do I crop the zalgo text properly? Is there a way? What's the root of the issue... why does substring not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common issue.  Redshift uses multi-byte UTF-8 encoding for non-ascii characters in varchar type data.  The varchar length definition is based on bytes, not characters.  When the data is ascii there is no difference so this distinction doesn't matter. But when non-ascii characters are used there is a difference in length.

Redshift has the functions len() and octet_length() which produce the character length and the byte length of a string - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OCTET_LENGTH.html

So there are a few ways you can fix this issue:

1. Change the code producing the S3 file to limit the strings to 200 bytes.  This may be easy or hard depending on what tool you are using.
2. Change the table definition to have enough room for all the multi-byte characters you are likely to see.  Since a multi-byte UTF-8 character cannot be more than 4 bytes, multiplying the length by 4 will solve it.  But carrying along columns that have been made 4X larger may have a performance issue if these are rare.  Also there may only be a few multi-byte characters per any value so 4X is overkill.
3. Ingest into a staging table that has the column 4X the size and then append the data to your main table limiting the octet_length to 200.  You can do this by finding the difference between octet_lengh() and len() in a substring() function.

=================================================================

UPDATE:

A lot of discussion in the comments and this should be summarized and clarified.

Redshift encodes varchar text in multi-byte UFT-8 as does much of the internet.  This format is a variable length encoding that can be as small as 1 byte per character and as much as 4 bytes per character.  The size depends on the character.  Basic ACSII characters are 1 byte, other characters (and symbols) take more than 1 byte to store.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 for a detailed description of UTF8 and how non-ascii characters are encoded.  See https://design215.com/toolbox/ascii-utf8.php for a table of all the 1 and 2 bytes UTF8 characters.

Also form Wikipedia:

> UTF-8 is the dominant encoding for the World Wide Web (and internet
> technologies), accounting for 97.9% of all web pages, over 99.0% of
> the top 10,000 pages, and up to 100% for many languages, as of 2023.
> Virtually all countries and languages have 95% or more use of UTF-8
> encodings on the web.

So any string of 200 characters can be of "byte size" anywhere between 200 bytes (all ascii characters) and 800 bytes (all characters that require 4 bytes to encode).  I've never worked with zalgo text so I don't know it's UTF-8 encoding nor how many bytes it takes per character.  Typically most string only have a limited number of characters that require 4 bytes but it doesn't happen especially with some rarer eastern character sets.  Your situation may be unique.

Varchar lengths in Redshift are in bytes, not characters.  This distinction is not important when text is all ascii.  So having multi-byte characters in a string can cause an unexpected errors. This seems to be what you are running into.

All string functions in Redshift operate on characters, except octet_length() which returns a strings length in bytes.  If you have a fixed varchar column size and you need to fit a string that is too long (in terms of bytes), you will need to trim the string down to fit.  You will also want to preserve as much of the original string as possible (or at least I would).  The challenge is to trim the minimum number of characters from your string, using the SQL functions available, such that the resulting string will fit in varchar(200) (200 bytes).

Let's assume that your S3 file has data that is of 200 characters or less.  Also that your target table for this data has a varchar(200) column for this data to be inserted into.  We can start by COPYing the S3 data into a staging table, "stage", that has a column, "txt", that is defined as varchar(800) - 200 characters X 4 bytes per characters worst case.

Now a common way to handle this in the case where a small subset of characters are more than 1 byte in size is to trim the number of characters down by how much the octet_length() is over the desired length of 200.  Which would look like:

```
select substring(txt, 1, 200 - (octet_length(txt) - len(txt))) as txt
from stage;
```

The problem with this is when the string has many multi-byte characters the result in zero length strings being produced.  So a more sophisticated approach is needed.

To complicate things we don't know where in the string the multi-byte characters are positioned. At the beginning, the end, or spread out.  But we don't want the SQL to fail with errors no matter what string we feed it.

One approach would be to use a proportional approach - if the string is 2X the desired size cut it in half.  This will get the resulting string close to the desired byte length but since the multi-byte characters could all be at the beginning this may still be too large.  A second step will be needed to fix up this corner case.

An approach like this might work (off the cuff):

```
with cte1 as (
select txt, 
  decode(octet_length(txt) < 200, len(txt), ((octet_length(txt) * ( 200::decimal(8,4) / octet_length((txt)))::int) as last_char
  -- FYI DECODE() is a simple version of CASE 
from stage ),
cte2 as (
select substring(txt, 1, last_char) as txt
from cte1)
select substring(txt, 1, 200 - (octet_length(txt) - len(txt))) as txt
from stage;
```

(that code is untested so sorry for any typos / bugs)

The first CTE just finds the proportion of the string that will approximately fit in 200 bytes.  The second CTE trims the string to this length.  The top select does the final trim of characters to ensure the result is < 200 bytes.

There may be others with better answers for how to keep the max number of characters while not going over 200 bytes.  This could be its own separate question on SO.

Comment: so if I multiple the column's character length by 4 in the staging table, then only take the first 200 characters when moving it into the redshift table, that should work right?

Comment: is `ACCEPTINVCHARS` useful in this case when copying to s3?

Comment: Not quite.  200 characters *COULD* be as much as 800 bytes and any number over 200 will cause the error.  In fact if you grab 200 characters and 1 of these characters is a multi-byte then there will be an error.  You need to take the first 200 characters, find the octet_length() of this substring, and then further truncate the string by the octet_length() - 200.  Or put differently you find how many bytes are in the first 200 characters and subtract character to ensure that the resulting string is less than 201 characters.  This could result in less than 200 character strings.

Comment: ACCEPTINVCHARS is for handling characters that are not properly encoded for Redshift (multi-byte UTF-8).  Having a file encoded as UTF-16 will have characters that Redshift won't understand.  This option tells to just ignore these characters and replace them with some other character, default '?'.  Since Redshift can read your files just find I don't think this option will help you.

Comment: but when moving the zalgo text from s3 to the redshift staging table, it'll get converted to mutlibytes utf-8 right? So say the zalgo text is 200 characters in s3, it'll get converted to 800 bytes in the redshift staging table and from there I can take the first 200 bytes when moving it to the final table right?

Comment: UFT-8 is also the file encoded needed for ingestion into Redshift.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-multi-byte.html.  If any conversion is needed it happens before COPY and since much of the data in the wild is UTF-8 you may not have run into this need.  As for how how many bytes each zalgo character takes, I have done the decode.  Multi-byte UTF-8 encoding can be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes long.  ASCII characters are 1 byte, most accented western characters are 2 bytes, 3 & 4 bytes chars are less common.  This makes payloads smaller most of the time.

Comment: Bill thanks for the discussion and answer

Comment: A Zalgo characters is likely 4 bytes but could be 3.  Non-zalgo characters will be their own size.  Is the data you are loading always zalgo and always completely zalgo?  If so then you math is likely right.  If a mix or different rows have different chars then this math won't hold.  The difference in string length in characters and string length in bytes will vary with the composition of the string.  So the math gets a little complex.

Comment: Also there is no function to take the first 200 bytes of a string.  Octet_length() gives you the byte size so this is the input you need.  So you can load the 200 chars into the staging table with a varchar size of 800 to be safe.  Then you want to save as much of the string as you can into your main table with a definition of varchar(200).  I'd grab the first 200 char from the staging table, find the octet_length of this portion, then subtract additional characters from the 200 by the number of bytes octet_lenth is over 200.  This may make your string less than 200 bytes by a bit.

Comment: The above is a common solution when there are some characters > 1 byte.  I can see if you have 200 zalgo characters this process will lead to 0 length strings.  If this is the kind of data you have then you will need some more complex math.  Like ratio 200 to the octet_length and use this to proportionally reduce the string, then use the process above to trim any characters that put you just a little over 200 bytes.

Comment: I think I have to concpetualize this better in my head. I'm confused because I thought the zalgo text gets stored as bytes when moving the data from s3 to redshift which is which is why increasing the varchar length in teh staging table to 800 helped. So now the staging table is storing something that is 800 bytes in length. I'm trying to figure out why I can't just take the first 200 of that and move it into the final table.

Comment: Let me update the answer as a lot of people are confused on this.